# Sharepoint 2013 Office365 - DelegateControl

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365-apps

I'm trying to find an official answer to my question:
Can I use DelegateControl in Sharepoint 2013 on **Office365**?

Does anyone have any Microsoft link or article where they say this is possible or not possible? Or any of you guys know for experience this is possible?

Thansk
Emilio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible to use Delegate Control as you can only install Sandboxed solutions in SharePoint 365 and Delegate Controls are not permitted in Sandboxed solutions.

Similar question asked Office365 community
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/55979.aspx

Richard diZerega has written a blog about what is possible and not possible on SharePoint 365
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/07/16/app-approaches-to-common-sharepoint-customizations.aspx

> **Delegate Control**
>   Apps for SharePoint do not support "Control" elements that can be used
>   with delegate controls in a master page. Delegate controls are a
>   common mechanism for swapping out functionality of a site using a farm
>   solutions (particularly useful with the AdditionalPageHead delegate).
>   As an alternative, the same result can be achieved through the design
>   in a custom master page (ex: place specific html or server controls in
>   the master page).